# Function for subtracting scalar from each element of an array

Tags: visual-c++, stl

I want to subtract a particular value from each of the values in a buffer B . So for example if the Buffer B contains the values as;

1000 1500 2000 200

then if the value to be subtracted is 5, the output should be:

995  1495 1995 195

Also if the difference comes negative, it should truncate to 0.

I know there are trivial ways for doing it, but I being a lazy person I am looking for some function for this purpose.

Is the any function in C/C++ for doing this?

**Update** 
Basically I am expecting that the function will be more optimized as compared to my trivial looping method. My buffer has 5000000 values, and this will be performed on  thousands of such buffers successively.

Comment: why not write a loop? I don't think you will find such a function in C/C++. However, boost might have some.

Comment: Laziness not good for coders...............:P

Answer (score 0):

One function like this:

```
void SubtractArray(vector<int>& coll)
{
    transform(coll.begin(), coll.end(), coll.begin(), [](int elem){
        return elem - 5 < 0 ? 0 : elem - 5;
    });
}
```